# How to save the data to database through dynamically loaded controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload

In my website I have used asp Fileupload control to upload the files and onclick of upload button a panel will be displayed in which the images uploaded will be displayed along with a textarea to write description of the image. After writing description I have to save the image into database alongwith description on click of dynamically created save button. Please give some idea on how to do this. My frontend code is as follows:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="transbox" id="mainbk" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" style="background-color:white; position:absolute; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 350px; right: 251px;" Width="500px" AllowMultiple="true"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" style="position:absolute;  font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 870px; width: 112px; height: 29px;" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
        <asp:Panel ID="updtpanel" runat="server" CssClass="transbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute" Visible="false">

        </asp:Panel>
     </div>


    </form>
```

and my backend code is as follows:

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
        {
           int tid = 0;

           string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName).ToLower();
           if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".bmp")
           {
               HtmlGenericControl d = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
               Button btnsave = new Button();
               btnsave.Text = "Save";


               sb.Append("<div class=" + "\"savback\"" + ">");
               sb.Append("<div class=" + "\"head\"" + ">Write Description</div>");

               foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
               {
                   id += 1;
                   tid = tid + 1;
                   string textid = "txt" + tid;
                   filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName);
                   uploadedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
                   newpath = "../Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName;
                   try
                   {
                       updtpanel.Visible = true;

                       sb.Append("<div class=" + "\"dataload\"" + ">");
                       sb.Append("<img class=" + "\"loadimg\"" + "src=" + "\"" + newpath.ToString() + "\"" + " />");
                       sb.Append("<textarea  class=" + "\"txtdes\"" + "id=" + "\"" + textid + "\"" + "></textarea>");
                       sb.Append("</div>");


                   }

                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Response.Write(ex.Message);
                   }

               }

               sb.Append("</div>");
               d.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

               updtpanel.Controls.Add(d);
               updtpanel.Controls.Add(btnsave);
           }
           else
           {
               Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Please Select only Image Files!!');", true);
           }

        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Please Select a File First!!');", true);        
        }
    }
```

and this is how it looks before uploading:[image: Before Uploading]

and after uploading it looks something like this[image: After Uploading and before Saving]

Please let me know how can I save this into database after entering the description in the textbox below the uploaded pic.

> I know everyone knows how facebook uploads album images right. Similarly I want to do after uploading Images and then save it in Database. In Facebook the description textbox will be created dynamically, if I am not wrong. how wil they refer to the contents of each description text box and save it in DB. Hope I am making it clear.

Comment: any specific reason for creating the save button dynamically?wont toggling the visibility work?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1895457/5353700.aspx/1?Re+dynamically+created+link+button+s+click+event+not+firing

Comment: @Karthik.. U see I have created only a panel during design and everything else inside it I am adding during run time. No specific reason but due to the design I followed I have to do so. Hmm will think about it, whether If i can change design. :)

Comment: @Karthik.. Lets say I create save button in design itself and toggle between its visibility. I will also right a onlclick event for that button. But now I just want to retrieve data contents from each of the textarea under the image and save it in DB. This I cannot create in design n it has to be created in run time itself. so do you have any idea how to get the contents from the dynamically created text area???

Answer (score 0):

in the database vision you need a table with at least 3 columns, first a VARBINARY column that is called BLOB column to store your file, second a VARCHAR column to store your file extension (e.g .gif, .jpeg) , third a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR column to store your caption. but the point is in your application you need to convert your file into array of bytes then pass it to sql server as varbinary parameter.

```
 private Byte[] getDocumentFormatter(string path)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return bytes;
        }
```

but in web environment you can replace path with your output buffer or any solutions you've got for you site.to conclude use a method like I mentioned above to get Byte[] array of your file, then pass it with file caption and file extension to a stored procedure in sql server.

Comment: I already have a table "slider" in my datatbase with 3 columns namely, slid int PK, slurl varchar, slalt varchar. do I need to add any extra things other then this???

Comment: yes , you need to add two more columns for example myFile VARBINARY(MAX) and myFileExtension VARHCAR(10).

Comment: because you need to format and build your file from VARBINAY and it does not include extension of the file, you need to save it and reuse it again when needed.